# Localization of location request permission

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, plist

How to localized location request permission content at application launching?
I have tried with . strings file and also available localize button with Info.plist.

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more?  shouldn't your app show content for whatever language the user has selected in iOS as their preference?

Comment: In your root project add a `InfoPlist.strings` file, then make it localizable, choose your local language, e.g., if request camera permission just put `"NSCameraUsageDescription" = "Your localization description";` in the file.